# What is the length of an EM wave that has a frequency of one cycle per hour?

Tags: waves

I would be grateful to get a formula for this or the exact answer. Thank you!

Comment: It's no different than the equation for the length of an EM wave that has a frequency of 1MHz, 1GHz, or 1THz, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "length" could be anything; it could be a really short pulse or a prolonged signal with that frequency. The *wavelength*, on the other hand, can be found using the equation $v=f\lambda$ where $v$ is the speed of the EM wave and $f$ is the frequency. The speed of the EM wave is $v=3\cdot 10^8$ m/s (its just the speed of light) and you're given that $f=\frac{1}{3600}$ (3600 seconds are in one hour). This gives us that $\lambda = 1.08 \cdot 10^{12}$ meters. However, this is pretty unrealistic, the longest EM waves are only [around $10^5$ meter](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/the-electromagnetic-spectrum/)s.

Comment: Yes, I mean "wavelength", of course, sorry for the missunderstanding! What happens with the EM waves at a length of 10/5 meters - why can't they be longer? I read about the redshift effect and how EM energy continuously shifts to a lower energy level/lower frequency with distance traveled, but I thought that a traveling EM wave travels indefinitely...

Comment: It does travel indefinitely, it's just that you're never going to find an EM wave that's $10^{12}$ meters long in the natural world (at least I don't think so, I'm not an exper in this topic)